# Searching for max value between two 2-3 Tree leafs

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have an 2-3 tree where each leaf consists of:

- Key
- Value

The tree is ordered by the keys.

I want to find the maximum value between 2 keys i < j (in domain [i,j]), within worst case O(logn).

It is clear to me that I need to store additional information such as "maximum in a subtree". However I can't come up with precise algorithm of going over all relevant subtrees to achieve my goal.

[EDIT]
I'm looking for something similar to the following thread:

[Search max value between 2 AVL nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035623/search-max-value-between-2-avl-nodes?lq=1)

The only difference is that I'm interested in 2-3 tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep `maxTreeValue` in each node, represents the maximum in this sub tree (should be updated after every modification, bottom-up starting from the modified node).

Start searching for both `i,j` simultaneously, stop at the node where the search paths split.

Search for `i` from that node. 
For each node in path, find the maximum between the sub-tree of each edge, from the next edge in `i`'s search path **exclusive** to the rightmost edge **inclusive**, or to the edge on the search path of `j` **exclusive**, the first between them.

Then do the same symmetrically for `j`, and return the max between them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to store extra information in the tree nodes.

Each 2-3 node has one or two keys, and 2 to 3 links. Set a variable `best_seen` to `nil`. Starting at the root of the tree, consider the following exhaustive cases:

1. All keys in the node are < i. Recurse to the right. [If there is any key satisfying the criteria, it must be to the right of this node.]
2. All keys in the node are > j. Recurse to the left. [If there is any key satisfying the criteria, it must be to the left of this node.]
3. One or both keys are between i and j; choose the larger key between i and j as the `best_seen`, and recurse to the right of `best_seen`. [If there is any key larger than `best_seen` satisfying the criteria, it will be to the right of that key.]
4. The node is `nil`, return `best_seen`

Assertion: `best_seen` is never replaced with a smaller value. (This is because we always recurse to the right after setting `best_seen`.)